# Layered Web Application in Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, performance, scalability

I would to know if it makes sense to build a web application in this way:

- Business Logic, Persistence and Web Services in Java EE
- Presentation Layer in PHP (which only do some routing and serves the pages)
- Client-side Javascript that communicates straight with Web Services

The business Logic has a single RESTful interface for both presentation layer and web API.
The presentation is almost client-side, php's purpose is only to route and retrieve some basically static data, it access to business logic throught Web Serivices too.

I want to know, is that possible? and, mostly, it makes sense?
And in case it is, is it a good solution for performance? And is it scalable? How about it in a distributed context?
Thank you all.

Comment: I'm curious, why wouldn't you keep everything in a single language such as PHP? PHP can perform business logic, persistence and web services as well. Generally if you mix languages you can open a can of worms. Consider various language level timeouts, sessions, etc.

Comment: For business logic I feel better with Java EE because of various things like EJB and JTA which I can not do without. Is not the same for presentation layer, I would just some lightweight library to do some url routing and JSF is too much overweight for this purpose. I thought PHP suits well to this job and this is it. I am considering this scenario also in case of a distributed system, so for instance the BL in one server and the presentation in another, I thought that RESTful service well replaces RMI and JMS.